# Access airflow dag run conf in UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I have airflow 1.10.12 installed on a server and I’ve launched a dag with a trigger dag configuration which is json. I know how to access the config in my dag’s code, but I want to get it in Airflow UI. Where should I look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very convenient, but you can view the DAG run conf via Browse -> DAG Runs -> view "Conf" column (and filter for your specific DAG run).

There is code on the main branch which adds a separate DAG run page, but that's not released yet: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/19705.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following:

1. Go to the Grid View for your DAG.
2. Click on the DAG Run you're interested in.

   - This is hard to describe, so take a look at the screenshot.
   - Sorry if you're visually impaired. I hope there's a way to do that in a more direct way.

You'll see the "Run config" displayed as one of the notes.

My company says they use 1.10, but I think we cherry-pick some changes from 2.x, so take it with a grain of salt. I just wasn't able to follow @Bas Harenslak's solution.

[image: Screenshot of where you should click on the Grid View. It's the bar that represents the dag run.]